# Check if Item has Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, subquery, having-clause

I have a table that contains a whole lot of fields.

What I am trying to do is see if any items are a missing certain fields.

Example of data:

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| ITEMNO | OPTFIELD | VALUE |
+--------+----------+-------+
| 0      | x        | 1     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| 0      | x        | 1     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| 0      | x        | 1     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| 0      | x        | 1     |
+--------+----------+-------+
| 0      | x        | 1     |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

There are 4 "OPTFIELD" which I want to see if all "ITEMNO" have.

So the logic I want to apply is something along the lines of:

Show all items that do not have the "OPTFIELD" - "LABEL","PG4","PLINE","BRAND"

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Your data makes no sense. From the description of your question, it looks like you want `itemno` that do not have all 4 `optfield`s. For this, one method uses aggregation:

```
select itemno
from mytable
where optfield in ('LABEL', 'PG4', 'PLINE', 'BRAND')
group by itemno
having count(*) < 4
```

On the other hand, if you want to exhibit all missing `(itemno, optfield)` tuples, then you can cross join the list of `itemno`s with a a derived table with of `optfield`s, then use `not exists`:

```
select i.itemno, o.optfield
from (select distinct itemno from mytable) i
cross join (values ('LABEL'), ('PG4'), ('PLINE'), ('BRAND')) o(optfield)
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t
    where t.itemno = i.itemno and t.optfield = o.optfield
)
```

Comment: Hello GMB,

Thank you for your reply.

The table has other "OPTFIELD" but the ones i am looking to see if they have are "LABEL","PG4","PLINE","BRAND".

These fields themselves are in theory optial files in our ERP and are not "NEED" to be added to the Item but in my scenario i need them to be and i cant find a way to see if they are not there if that makes sense ?